# How would this oil filler cap have been damaged?

Tags: oil

If you look closely at this at the bottom of this oil filler cap you can see the plastic has chipped.

I’m not sure if it was already like that or if I did it whilst trying to force it into the rocker cover hole as it was the wrong size.  If so how would this have caused this part to chip?  It may have fallen into the valve train in which case do I need to worry about it or will it just get crushed and not affect performance?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnHHD.jpg)

[image]

Comment: By a gorilla forcing it. Any bits may end up in the sump or could damage a vital part. Find it or risk it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the threads on the cap are a different pitch to the threads in the engine cover, then there will be sideways forces on the threads that could have caused that chip.

There are large oil ways from the cylinder head to the sump, so if the chip has dropped inside the engine, it will likely quickly find its way to the sump and be either caught in the oil filter or by the gauze that is usually present on the oil pump pickup pipe.

There is a very small risk it could cause an issue to the camshaft components, but I think it is highly unlikely.  You will have to decide whether that risk warrants the removal of the engine cover to search for the chip.